# Managed C++ Static Constructor not called in .net4

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli

I've recently moved a project I'm working on from .NET 3.5 to .NET 4. I'm using C#, Managed C++ and Unmanaged C++.

In one of my Managed C++ (interop) I'm having a static constructor:

```
public ref class StaticPool : public BaseStaticPools
{
public:
    static StaticPool()
    {                       
        InitializePools();
    }

    static Poolable^ Dequeue()
    {
        return (Poolable^)Dequeue(Poolable::typeid);
    }

private:
    static void InitializePools()
    {                       
        BaseStaticPools::CreatePool(Poolable::typeid);                      
    }
};
```

In .NET 3.5 once `Dequeue()` had been called for the first time it would trigger the static initialization, which runs the static constructor. Once I moved to .NET 4.0, the static constructor was never called.

I know there have been changes in static initializations in .NET 4.0, but according to all I read it should work fine.

Comment: "Managed C++" as in [Managed Extensions for C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa712574(v=vs.71).aspx) or [C++/CLI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163852.aspx)?

Comment: Managed C++ is .NET 1.x only, it was replaced by C++/CLI.  I fixed your tags.

Comment: @Samuel: Since the code has `^` for handles, instead of `__gc *`, it can't be Managed Extensions for C++.

Comment: @BenVoigt Good point - I didn't notice that. I was also unaware that Managed C++ is .NET 1.x only.

Comment: Thanks you all for clearing it up, I'm new to this area so I guess I'll need some more reading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In .NET, type initializers may only be called the first time a field is accessed.  This is controlled by the `[BeforeFieldInit]` attribute.

I filed a bug report, which is only available to beta testers, despite being marked "Public".

Here's the explanation from Microsoft, which you may find helpful:

> For C++, this is the intended behavior. We mark our classes with `BeforeFieldInit`, and so the initialization the CLR is performing is correct. We do not offer a way in C++/CLI to change this behavior. If you require the class constructor to run, you are able to call `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers::RunClassConstructor` explicitly.

---

> Since we're invoking the standard here, the line from Partition I, 8.9.5 says this:
>
> If marked BeforeFieldInit then **the type’s initializer method is executed at, or sometime before, first access to any static field** defined for that type.
>
> That section actually goes into detail about how a language implementation can choose to prevent the behavior you're describing. C++/CLI chooses not to, rather they allow the programmer to do so if they wish.
>
> Basically, **since the code below has absolutely no static fields, the JIT is completely correct in simply not invoking static class constructors**.

Comment: the link you put is corrupted.

Comment: Yep, I couldn't open the link. However, I'm calling the static method, isn't that enough for triggering the static constructor?

Comment: @Adban: nothing wrong with the link, but apparently the issue page is only visible to beta testers.

Comment: @Lior: Since you can't get to the issue page, I've copied the important explanation here.  Essentially the answer is "no, calling a static method isn't enough".

Comment: Ben Voigt: Thanks a lot for the effort. However, I did try accessing a static filed but it still didn't invoke the static constructor. In addition, the weird thing that it works fine in .NET 3.5 and when I run in .NET v4.0 in debug mode.

Comment: @Lior: Quite so.  In fact my original bug report was about the different behavior between debug and release.

Comment: OK, I think I found a solution. The static member I called was int which probably doesn't need any initialization. I've added a new object member which is initialized from the static ctor and everything works. Breaking change in .NET?

Comment: @Lior: It's a breaking change in implementation, but you (and I) were relying on implementation details to begin with.  The guarantee .NET makes of "at or sometime before" leaves a lot of flexibility.  The static constructor could be run as soon as the module loaded, and they'd still be in compliance with the spec.

Comment: I notice this bug was marked as fixed about 6 months ago by Microsoft.  Has anyone experienced this fix actually working?  Is it available in .Net 4.0 or do we have to wait for Visual Studio 11/.Net 4.5 to mature?

Comment: @ebyrob: There is no "fix".  The explanation from Microsoft, as I understand it, is that C++/CLI behaves according to `BeforeFieldInit` as specified in the .NET Standard, not according to the examples in the ECMA standard for C++/CLI (examples are non-normative anyway).

Answer (score 3):

Jon Skeet wrote on this topic:

[Type initialization changes in .NET 4.0](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/01/26/type-initialization-changes-in-net-4-0/)