# Generating initialization code for .dll

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I recently heard that it is possible for a .dll to run code as soon as it is loaded, when an application which references the .dll is loaded, for example. Event though I made some tests of my own and tried looking for answers here and on Google I was unable to find some way to generate an initialization method for a .dll.

I would like to know if it is really possible to run code from a .dll when it is loaded by an application.

If so, how can I do so?

Comment: What's your concrete use case? Because depending on it you could use other mechanisms like static constructors...

Comment: I am developing a library (.dll) which users could use as trial or licensed. I would like to communicate with a server in order to check for license and get some statistics about the usage of my product.

Comment: So you may use a static constructor spy, I'll post an answer.

Comment: You probably have wrong tags for this question - C++ and WinAPI would be more appropriate for `DllMain` which is what you probably heard about... I'm not aware of any code that would be automatically run on loading of managed assembly.

Comment: Based on your comment it is unclear why do you need such potentially dangerous and confusing behavior. Doing check on first reasonable call into method of your library would be significantly more reliable and easier.

Comment: Also, don't forget that it's possible for the user to modify your DLL to avoid the initialization code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

WARNING (thanks *Ben Voigt* for the catch :)): the below code applies only to **C#** that guarantees that the generated class **won't be beforefieldinit**.
But with **C++/CLI** should not work as easily: [Managed C++ Static Constructor not called in .net4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989003/managed-c-static-constructor-not-called-in-net4)

---

So as stated in my comment you may use something like this:

```
using System;

class MyAwesomeLibrary
{
    static MyAwesomeLibrary()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Hey {0} is using me!", Environment.UserName));
    }
    
    public static int GetTheAnswer()
    {
        return 42;
    }
}

class Client
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The answer is: " + MyAwesomeLibrary.GetTheAnswer());
    }
}
```

In the static constructor you can do advanced things like checking the registry, communicating with a server...

And if you're a bad guy (or just a developer/company who wants to protect its rights) you can throw an exception:

```
throw new Exception("The library has not been correctly registered...");
```

This will result in a [TypeInitializationException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.typeinitializationexception.aspx) preventing the use of the whole library class.

Or you can implement a *CheckMe* method ans asks all the user to call it before using the library or even to authenticate and get a security token they'll use each time they use something...

EDIT:

Whatever the protection you use a determined attacker could circumvent all the plumbing by decompiling the library so if you can you should **obfuscate** your library too to be (a little) more protected.

Comment: +1 as it shows practical sample. Also this does not answer the question as asked - no code executed on "assembly load", but rather on using method of a type.

Comment: This won't prevent use of the whole library. Just use of the type whose constructor threw an exception. You would have to put code in the static constructor of every public type to do that.

Comment: @Alexei: that right but as mentioned it in my last sentence it may be better to have something more explicit like a dedicated method, at least the client knows why it crashes. _@mike: right it's why I've written "the whole library class", not "the whole library" :). And you can also design your library with a central factory that only returns interfaces, never exposing concrete implementation except the factory itself.

Comment: The static constructor won't run until something accesses a static field. Have you tested your example in release mode?

Comment: @BenVoigt: yes I've checked in release mode (to be exact: "csc /debug- /optimize+ Test.cs"). AFAIK if there is a static ctor the class cannot be marked as **beforefieldinit** (C#) and if not marked as **beforefieldinit** the static ctor should be called when "using" the class (i.e. using any of the instance or static members) (ECMA 335). Here is an article that comfort this reasoning: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/beforefieldinit.html I'm not at all comfortable with all this low level stuff (I'm an applications programmer) and may be completely wrong so please correct me. Thanks :)

Comment: But this question is tagged as c++-cli. It would be good to update your answer to say that the static constructor approach only would work in c#.

Answer (score 2):

To long for comment...

Note that putting non-trivial code (i.e. slow remote network call) into startup code of any kind (like static constructor of an important  class) will alienate users of your library. It may force them to write special code to avoid random delays on load/method call.

Simply having "validate license" method in the library is probbly better solution.

Note that "phone home" feature itself is often not very welcome by users and better be well documented. Especially if you want your library to be usable as part of someone else programs.

Answer (score -1):

You can call the dll code in application constructor.
This is the point where assemblies are resolved.

Comment: This does not answer the question and also incorrect - assemblies are loaded whey they are needed for first time; properly written application would try to minimize amount of dependencies in startup code...

Comment: I always thought that they are loaded at startup, turns out it was because I always used referenced assemblies in main class. I checked and you were right.

Comment: What exactly is this “application constructor”? If you mean the constructor of class deriving from `Application`, then that's WPF-specific. And it certainly doesn't have anything to do with resolving assemblies.

Comment: By application constructor I mean Application derived class constructor in WPF in Main in Program.cs in WinForms and ConsoleApp.
It does have something to do with resolving assemblies - this is the point where you can to [this](http://www.digitallycreated.net/Blog/61/combining-multiple-assemblies-into-a-single-exe-for-a-wpf-application)